# FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission. Could not generate device token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'     

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

This is my gradle setup. I wrote code to receive device token extending `FirebaseMessagingService`, but could not generate device token.

Comment: Check your google-services.json file. It has to be generated by Android studio if you used firebase wizard. If it is not there then import it from firebase console

Comment: share you code of generating device token.......